# Unable to update progress in ProgressBar of Notification using WorkManager

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I want to create a long-running worker for downloading a video. As per my understanding, we should call `createForegroundInfo()` to update the ongoing notification. However, I can't find the information on how should I update the determinate progress bar shown in the notification. As shown below, I tried calling the `createForegroundInfo()` function whenever the progress is updated but the progress bar in the notification is not getting updated.

**Note:** As you can see in the below code, I am using `setProgress(100, downloadProgress, false)` as omitting the line didn't show the progress bar in the notification at all.

```kotlin
private fun createForegroundInfo(downloadProgress: Int, videoTitle: String): ForegroundInfo {
        createNotificationChannel()

        val cancelText = applicationContext.getString(R.string.all_text_cancel)
        val cancelPendingIntent =
            WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).createCancelPendingIntent(id)

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(
            applicationContext,
            applicationContext.getString(R.string.app_download_channel_id)
        )
            .setContentTitle(videoTitle)
            .setTicker(videoTitle)
            .setProgress(100, downloadProgress, false)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_close, cancelText, cancelPendingIntent)
            .build()

        return ForegroundInfo(notificationId, notification)
    }
```

I also tried updating the progress as shown below but that only updates the progress observed in the Fragment using LiveData and the progress bar in the notification doesn't get updated.

```kotlin
val lastUpdate = workDataOf("Progress" to progress)
setProgress(lastUpdate)
```

Also as shown below, I observed that the documentation mentions that we should call `setForegroundInfo()` and not `createForegroundInfo()` in order to update the ongoing notification. However, there is no method named `setForegroundInfo()`.

[image]

As mentioned, I can't find the method to update the progress bar of the ongoing notification. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `DownloadManager` would do just that, with a progress bar. Unless knowing the ID of the notification, you're likely not going to update that notification, as it is unknown which one notification is meant.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am trying to download a video from m3u8 link which DownloadManager doesn't support.

Comment: The official documentation (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running#long-running-kotlin) shows the exact answer marked as solution just a few lines above the screenshot!

    // Mark the Worker as important <br>
    val progress = "Starting Download"<br>
    setForeground(createForegroundInfo(progress))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there is a mistake in the documentation and the methods name is `setForeground()` instead of `setForegroundInfo()`. I was able to update the progress in the notification by using the code shown below.

```kotlin
setForeground(createForegroundInfo(progress, videoTitle))
```

**createForegroundInfo()**

```kotlin
private fun createForegroundInfo(downloadProgress: Int, videoTitle: String): ForegroundInfo {
        createDownloadNotificationChannel()

        val cancelText = applicationContext.getString(R.string.all_text_cancel)
        val cancelPendingIntent =
            WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).createCancelPendingIntent(id)

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(
            applicationContext,
            applicationContext.getString(R.string.app_download_channel_id)
        )
            .setContentTitle(videoTitle)
            .setContentText("Downloading")
            .setTicker(videoTitle)
            .setProgress(100, downloadProgress, false)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_close, cancelText, cancelPendingIntent)
            .build()

        return ForegroundInfo(notificationId, notification)
    }
```

Comment: Perfect Solution !

Answer (score 2):

Need to add following line before return statement in above answer. Otherwise notification will not be shown.

```
notificationManager.notify(1(any Int value), notification.build())
```

Also declare notificationManager at the beginning of class.

```
private lateinit var notificationManager: NotificationManagerCompat
```

Initialize it as,

```
notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31960879)